# How to get all the data from gridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working in vb.net and I have to get all data of gridview column(2) and store it in the dictionary of string.
Is it possible to do that ?

I found this:

```
Dim x As Integer x = dgvName.Rows(yourRowIndex).Cells(yourColumnIndex).Value
```

but in my code I can get the value attribute for gridview cells

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: can u give any example for that pls?

Comment: Mr. [Google](https://www.google.com.ph/search?source=hp&ei=5F0zWvj2JoGc8QXj3p6gDQ&q=vb.net+dictionary+example&oq=vb.net+dictiona&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0l10.10559.13596.0.15087.17.12.0.0.0.0.458.1780.2-5j0j1.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..11.6.1780.0..46j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i46k1.0.AryC7QbDktE) can help you. Have you tried searching before posting?

Comment: yes but not found proper solution

Comment: Mr. Google returned 183,000 hits for "how to retrieve data from datagrid in vb.net" and not one helped you?

Comment: no because i got this solution:                                                                    "Dim x As Integer    
x = dgvName.Rows(yourRowIndex).Cells(yourColumnIndex).Value"  but in my code i can get the value attribute for gridview cells

Comment: so your problem is solved?

Comment: no, not yet solved

Comment: You need to include code. Read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: It is possible, but also not needed.  DataBinding and the NET DB Privider will "get" the data for you.  If you want a good answer you need to post a good question.  Like almost all of your past question, this one is not.  Read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: `get all data of gridview column(2) and store it in the dictionary of string`  You don't need this.  The data is already in the grid.  Your "key" would be the row index.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
variable1 = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("lastName").Value
variable2 = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("firstName").Value
```

If you want a specific cell, you can do this:

```
Dim x As Integer    
x = dgvName.Rows(yourRowIndex).Cells(yourColumnIndex).Value
```

Or

```
datagridviewName(columnFirst, rowSecond).value
```